# Google Cloud Platform project is being suspended

Tags: security, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, denial-of-service

I've received an email from Google declaring that they have suspended my project due to denial of service attacks

> Dear Developer, We have recently detected that your Google Cloud
>   Project My Project (id: xxx-yyy-zzz) has been committing denial of
>   service attacks and is violating our Terms of Service. Your project My
>   Project (id: xxx-yyy-zzz) is therefore being suspended

Promptly after this email was sent, Google has shut down all the machines Compute Engine instances associated with the project and I had to appeal in order to receive access. Google has requested that I investigate and it seems indeed that an unsuccessful breaking attempt has been made, however I'm not sure what else to check. Here's what I've checked :

**Apache logs**

Seems like there's suspicious activity with a lot of entries such as :

```
GET /muieblackcat HTTP/1.1 404 470 
GET //pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1 404 479 
GET //mysql/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1 404 481
GET //mysqladmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1 404 486
GET //MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1 404
GET //myadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1 404
GET //phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1 404 486
GET //phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1 404 486
```

**Activity monitoring in the Google cloud console**

I do see a spike in outgoing packet activity, which explains why Google has triggered the alarm

[image: Google Cloud bytes out activity]

**SSH auth logs**

Seeing a lot of entries of invalid user trying to log into the instance :

```
Oct  8 18:07:41 instance-1 sshd[32486]: Invalid user aPlcmSpIp from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:07:47 instance-1 sshd[32488]: Invalid user admin from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:07:55 instance-1 sshd[32490]: Invalid user ubnt from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:08:02 instance-1 sshd[32492]: Invalid user fax from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:08:08 instance-1 sshd[32494]: Invalid user user1 from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:08:23 instance-1 sshd[32498]: Invalid user admin from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:08:33 instance-1 sshd[32500]: Invalid user test from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:08:41 instance-1 sshd[32503]: Invalid user admin from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:08:51 instance-1 sshd[32505]: Invalid user user1 from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:08:55 instance-1 sshd[32507]: Invalid user support from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:09:02 instance-1 sshd[32509]: Invalid user ftp from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:09:14 instance-1 sshd[32513]: Invalid user user from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:09:20 instance-1 sshd[32515]: Invalid user demo from 88.168.134.63
Oct  8 18:09:30 instance-1 sshd[32517]: Invalid user user from 88.168.134.63
```

Seeing a large number of attempts during the time of the attack

**Rootkit hunter**

I installed *rkhunter* and ran the check, no special warnings was introduced there

So definitely my instance was a target for an attack which somehow triggered excessive outgoing traffic. What further can I do to investigate the reason for suspending my project, and to protect this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1):

You should run an anti virus scan on your virtual machines. You can try Clamav. You can also run Linux Malware Detect.